# Is there anything wrong with splitting a complicated view into many small ones?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, view

I have a view where each row is associated with a customer, and the columns are various computed values such as `life_time_value` and `purchases_per_week`, as well as more complicated statistical values such as `probability_of_buying_premium_membership`. I have around 20 such columns of varying complexity (both in terms of lines-of-code and also computational complexity), ranging from a single line of SQL to several dozen. Right now they are all in one monster view.

Is there a down-side to splitting them into multiple smaller views and joining them by `customer_id`?

Ie, break it down into views called
`customer_life_time_value`, `customer_purchases_per_week` and so on, and then recreate the monster view by joining 20 views? It seems like there shouldn't be a performance hit because of the joining, as it's over a indexed primary key. Many of the columns/views will perform similar calculations (`purchases_per_week` and `purchases_per_quarter` would look very similar), but it seems like the DB should be smart enough to share computation if I am selecting from the joined view.

I am using Postgres, but interested for answers in general.

Comment: It is hard to answer the question without more detailed information. But what you describes sounds like the anti-pattern that I call "world view": a single view that joind and denormalizes the whole database, and which is used everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a down-side to splitting them into multiple smaller views and joining them by `customer_id`?

Yes, definitely. Each view has to scan the whole underlying table on its own, and then you add 20 joins after that. The index does not apply to the derived tables you are joining. The single `SELECT` can make do with a single scan over the table (or index), it should be *substantially* cheaper.

Proof: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e2c7376554569a72f5a5969860633c68)*

Comment: Does it matter if each individual view is `FROM` the customer table as well? I was hoping that if I did something like `select * from view1 join view2 using (customer_id) where name = 'Joe'`, where view1 is something like `create view view1 as select some_awesome_calculation(cust.stuff) from customers` and similar for the other views, that the database would be smart enough not to scan `customers` each time per view. Either way, do you have pointers on where to learn such implementation issues?

Comment: "*Each view has to scan the whole table on its own*" - I don't think that's true. Postgres will optimize the whole statement, not each view individually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Postgres optimizes whole statements. But my explanation still applies. I added a demo.